# What is equivalent of "dispatch_apply" in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have been searching for an equivalent of dispatch_apply in swift3. Help me please

convert

```
    let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_apply(2, queue) { (index)  in
    }
```

Comment: `DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations:`

Answer (score 28):

Do you still remember **dispatch_apply()**. Well, it's still there and got a new name. From now on you have to call **concurrentPerform()**

change this

```
dispatch_apply(2, queue) { (index)  in
}
```

into

```
DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: 2) {
print("\($0). concurrentPerform")
}
```